# Check existence of values in array on multi select dropdown focusout in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

i have a default array that have some fixed values from which i am showing a multiselect dropdown to user.So on focusout of the drop down i want to check that whether the values are selected have the all those values that are in the default array.If the values are missing i want to alert them to the user

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="selectedItemLists">Select values:</label>
        <select id="selectedItemLists" name="selectedItemLists" multiple>
            <option val="value1" selected >value1</option>
            <option val="value2">value2</option>
            <option val="value3" selected>value3</option>
            <option val="value4">value4</option>
            <option val="value5">value5</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
var default_values = ["value1","value3"];

$("#selectedItemLists").live('focusout',function(){
    var new_selectedvalues = $("#selectedItemLists").val();

    //here i want to compare both the arrays and alert him that default values are missing
});
```

Comment: **Note:** `.live()` is deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9 consider using `.on()` if your jQuery version is 1.7+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple nested `$.each` loop will do it:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T64Wb/)**

```
//here i want to compare both the arrays and alert him that default values are missing
$.each(default_values, function(_, defaultVal){
    var found = false;
    $.each(new_selectedvalues, function(){
        if(this == defaultVal){
            found = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(!found){
        alert("Please select the default: " + defaultVal);   
    }
});
```

Note: `.live()` is deprecated from jQuery 1.7, so `.on` should be used instead (unless you are working with the old version).

Comment: can you suggest something on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060024/send-multipart-data-in-ajax-jquery

Answer (score 0):

please use

```
$("#selectedItemLists").on('blur',function(){
```

instead of

```
$("#selectedItemLists").live('focusout',function(){
```

**live is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9**

try this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LeeSS/2/)**

```
var default_values = ["value1", "value3"];

$("#selectedItemLists").on('blur', function () {
    var missing_values  = [];;

    var values = $(this).val();
    //******************************************
    //checking missing values in default_values
    //******************************************
    $.each(values, function (key, value) {

        if ($.inArray(value, default_values) == -1) {
            missing_values.push(value);
        }
    });
    alert(missing_values); 
    // alerts missing selected values in default_values
});
```

or try

```
var default_values = ["value1", "value3"];

$("#selectedItemLists").on('blur', function () {
    var missing_values  = [];

    var values = $(this).val();        
    //******************************************
    //checking default values in selection
    //******************************************
    $.each(default_values, function (key, value) {

        if ($.inArray(value, values) == -1) {
            missing_values.push(value);
        }
    });
    alert(missing_values); 
    // alerts missing default values in selected
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do someting like this:

```
var default_values = ["value1","value3"];    
var displayValues = [];
$("#selectedItemLists").on('blur',function(){
    $.each(default_values, function(index, value) {
        if($.inArray(value, $("#selectedItemLists").val()) === -1)
        {
            displayValues.push(value);
        }
    });
});

alert(displayValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
var default_values = ["value1","value3"];

$("#selectedItemLists").on('blur',function(){
    var values = $(this).val();

    if ($(values).not(default_values).length == 0 && $(default_values).not(values).length == 0) {
        console.log('equal');
    } else {
        console.log('not equal');
    }                       
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f5BbT/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var default_values = ["value1","value3"];

$("#selectedItemLists").focusout(function() {
    var selected_val = $('#selectedItemLists').val();
    if(selected_val.length < default_values.length){
        alert('value not present');
    }else{
        var flag = true;
        for(var i= 0;i<default_values.length;i++){
            if(selected_val.indexOf(default_values[i]) == -1){
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        if(!flag){
            alert('value not present');
        }else{
            alert('value present');
        }
    }
});
```